# Sound doesn't play on ipad 2 while receiving push notification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad-2

When push notification is received on device i.e. iPad 2 of ios 3, the sound doesn't exists on iPad 2 of ios 3.

Comment: which iOS version you are using in your iPad2?

Comment: Are you using custom audio or system audio for sound?

Comment: Make sure the sound's file name is same, both notification aps payload and sound file which exist in your bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of these:

A) Filename in payload is invalid

B) File is missing

C) Device is silenced

D) Ringer volume is zero (different to regular volume, check settings > Sound)

E) Notification settings for your app have sound switched off

F) Your speakers are broken